# Setting static IP address disconnects Internet

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, static-ip

I wish to host a personal website on CentOs-7 Operating system. For that I bought a static IP address from my internet service provider (Hathway). They provided me a static IP address, subnet (255.255.255.0), gateway, and two DNS addresses. Then I asked google for my IP address and google showed my public IP address which is same as the one provided by the ISP as static IP. Then I entered the static IP on my browser on the same machine and it showed me my router's login page (ZTE-F612W). Then I tried to access the same address form another device which is connected to Internet, But it failed connecting to my static IP. At this time my network interface configuration was as bellow,

**old network script**

[image: old network script]

at this time `ifconfig` command showed me the following result,

**old ifconfig result**

[image: old ifconfig result]

then I updated my configuration scripts to add the information provided by ISP as bellow,

**new network script**

[image: new network script]

Then I restarted the network services and executed `ifconfig` again, and It showed me as bellow,

**new ifconfig result**

[image: new ifconfig result]

Now, I am not able to connect to the Internet. When I am trying to connect to my static IP from browser on my machine It shows my Apache web server page,and when i am trying to connect to my static IP from an external Internet machine It displays unable to connect.

How can I use this static IP to make my machine accessible through Internet?

Comment: No offense, but this question demonstrates a big lack of understanding how ISPs implement static IP addresses with their customers. All this is not going to get explained in a single question / answer format. Reach out to your ISP and have them explain how to implement the static IP address properly. How you do it is highly dependent on your entire network topology. What you have described is not how it works unless the server is the only device on your network, is plugged directly in to the modem, and you put the ISP modem in bridge mode.

Comment: This question sounds off-topic for [sf]. Additionally you should not be posting screenshots of terminal output. Instead copy the text into the question and use the code formatting option.

Comment: @Appleoddity It sounds like a lot of the confusion here is due to the presence of NAT. We were supposed to be passed the point where that temporary hack was necessary, alas that has not happened yet and lots of networks still rely on NAT. I do not consider lack of knowledge of NAT to imply lack of understanding, as it is possible to understand a properly operated IP network without any knowledge of NAT. I do however have a few other issues with this question.

Comment: @kasperd it seems like you’re putting words in my mouth, so to speak. We likely have the same concerns about this question. I didn’t say anything about NAT. I specifically said the OP doesn’t understand this properly, which includes fundamentals specific to ISP implementation of static IP addresses that are also highly dependent on the OP’s network topology. None of that can be answered based on the information given, and would require a great deal of explanation to accomplish anyways. This question is too broad and lacks necessary info to answer.

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes, this question should be closed for multiple reasons. I am not going to look through the screenshots to see if they contain enough information to answer the question, since there are other reasons why this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your new IP address and Default Gateway should be in the same subnet as before. Changing the IP address of your PC won't change what subnet other devives on the network are connected to. Basically, your new IP address should be somewhere between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254, and your default gateway should ideally say the same.
Try to figure out what the devices are that are already connected to your subnet (other PC's, maybe a TV, your router). Normally the standard default gateway should be your router.
Within the range 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254, you can take any address that isn't already used by another device.

The problem you are facing is that the IP address you have bought is how it will be visible on the public domain. Try to read a little bit more about [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). This is vital to your problem and any further explanation requires at least some basic knowledge about this subject. Also, knowing what [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) is and how it works can also give some more insight.